# New thread never completes waiting on WebBrowser

Tags: c#, multithreading

In creating jpg images, this code uses threading. However, the `Thread.Join()` sometimes hangs on creating particular images. I have researched, and it seems as if I should be using `BeginInvoke()` instead.  How could I rewrite the following code from using `Thread.Join()` to `BeginInvoke()`?

```
public Bitmap Generate()
{
    var m_thread = new Thread(_Generate);
    m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    m_thread.Start();
    m_thread.Join();

    return m_Bitmap;
}

private void _Generate()
{
   var browser = new WebBrowser {ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
   browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
   browser.Navigate(m_Url);
   browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

   while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
   {
       Application.DoEvents();
   }
   browser.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser Control in a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I see one issue. You've registered to the DocumentCompleted event after the Navigate() call. So theoretically it's possible that the event have been fired before you've registered your handler.
Try to swap the two lines and see whether you get your problem fixed.
I believe that'll be the case if the image has already been retrieved and was cached.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your help.  This did not resolve the issue.

Comment: So you said the issue can be reproduced for specific images, right ?If so, does the problem reproes, when you call the Generate for just one of those images ?

Comment: I researched this issue some more, and it seems that I was having some memory and caching issues.  I got the code to successfully work now.  Thank you.